# How do I copy a local file to Azure Databricks DBFS filestore

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, dbutils

I am using the below command in Azure Databricks to try and copy the file test.csv from the local C: drive to the Databricks dbfs location as shown.

```
dbutils.fs.cp("C:/BoltQA/test.csv", "dbfs:/tmp/test_files/test.csv")
```

I am getting this error:

```
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: C
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExecutionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3936625823332356> in <module>
----> 1 dbutils.fs.cp("C:/test.csv", "dbfs:/tmp/test_files/test.csv")
      2 

/local_disk0/tmp/1605164901540-0/dbutils.py in f_with_exception_handling(*args, **kwargs)
    312                     exc.__context__ = None
    313                     exc.__cause__ = None
--> 314                     raise exc
    315             return f_with_exception_handling
    316
```

Help please.

Answer (score 1):

The local files can be recognised with `file://...` so make a change to the command similar to below

```
dbutils.fs.cp("file://c:/user/file.txt",<container path>)
```

Comment: No, it won't work because in this case local means "local to the driver node", not to your local computer.

Comment: I am a little late to the party here... but it is possible to upload to Databricks using a local file on local computer using Databricks-CLI. You have to run it subprocess terminal command (if you want to automate with it. But checkout here: https://docs.databricks.com/en/archive/dev-tools/cli/index.html)